# Callback function fires in both success/error cases

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a **Nodejs/Express API** using **Mongoose** and **Mongo**.

I have a function that does an update.

The update works, but for some reason, it also always logs an error.

Here is the block of code I'm referring to:

```
Contacts.update(
  {
    'shared.emails._id': emailId
  }, 
  {
    $set: {
      'shared.emails.$.email_address': emailAddress,
      'shared.emails.$.email_type': emailType
    }
  }, 
  {
    'multi': true
  },
  function(err) {
    console.log('Error in updating shared emails: ', err);
  }
)
```

Does this not look right to anyone?

Comment: Are you sure that `err` is not `null`?. If it's not, what's the value it logs? I haven't used mongoose extensively but AFAIK your callback function will always fire. It is considered to have an error only if the `err` value is not null.

Comment: The err returns a null value

Comment: The callback is also triggered on success, not only on error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback parameter will *always* fire, even if the operation was succesful.

You should check if `err` has a truthy value, if it does then it threw an error, otherwise it was a success.

Here's an example:

```
  // ...
    'multi': true
  },
  function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return console.error(err);
    }

    // otherwise it was a success
    console.log('Updated');
  }
)
```

Keep in mind that the above code is just for illustrating the concept.

It is expected that you pass a callback function to this, which will follow the same concept so calling code can be notified of the status of the operation.

This is the [standard way of doing error handling](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/03/understanding-error-first-callbacks-in-node-js/) in Node.js callback-based code.